# Error handling for "required" keyword in html form submission

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am making a difficult design decision right now. I have a bunch of blanks in a form and two buttons in a html page, the two buttons are for "add" and "delete" data to/from a database (assuming that I have a method to retrieve data from the database and populate the form before deletion). I want to make a error handling mechanism such that
1) required fields must be filled before submission, and 
2) empty form (hence record) cannot be deleted

The code I have is similar to the following:

```
<form id="fm" method="POST">
  <input name="a" required>
  <input name="b" required>
  <!-- let's say I have 20 other blank fields -->
  <button id="add"><input name="btn">Add</button>
  <button id="delete"><input name="btn">Delete</button>
</form>
```

In my jquery, I have:

```
$("#fm").submit( function() {
  return false;
});
$("#sbmbtn").click( function() {
  $.post(............)
  //and other magic tricks
});
```

If I were to put everything in `.click` function into the `.submit` function, javascript will automatically enforcing that "required" fields must be filled before submission. However, if i were to do this, the other button will behave oddly because both buttons are in the same form, and clicking on either one will trigger form submission, which is not desirable.

Long story short, I probably won't change the architecture much, what can I add or tweak to make sure the required fields are checked before submission?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. required fields must be filled before submission, run this function before submission

   ```
   function validate() {
        var requiredFields = $('#fm input').filter('[required]');
        var valid = true;

        $.each(requiredFields, function(index, value){
            if (value.value.length < 1) {
               valid = false;
            }
        });

        return valid;
   }
   ```

and then use the return value from validate to make sure all fields are filled before running your submit function.

2. just disable the delete button if the form is empty

Edit: but all this will be useless if the user disables JavaScript so you have to have server side validation as well.